# Ajax Request in Typo3 v10: Calling controller action via typeNum

Tags: ajax, typoscript, extbase, typo3-10.x

I am trying to call an Extbase controller action via Javascript/Ajax.
The version is Typo3 v10. The controller action is supposed to return JSON.

I have created the controller and the action as follows:

```
namespace Thevendor\Theextension\Controller;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseFactoryInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\Response;

class ExampleController
{
   /** @var ResponseFactoryInterface */
   private $responseFactory;

   public function __construct(ResponseFactoryInterface $responseFactory)
   {
      $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
   }
  
    public function doSomethingAction(ServerRequestInterface $request): Response
    {       
       error_log("controller action got called!");
       $data = ['result' => 42];
       $response = $this->responseFactory->createResponse()
          ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
       $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($data));
       return $response;    
    }
}
```

Next, I have registered a plugin in ext_localconf.php:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
            'Thevendor.Theextension',
            'Testing',
            [
                \Thevendor\Theextension\Controller\ExampleController::class => 'doSomething',               
            ],
            // non-cacheable actions
            [
                \Thevendor\Theextension\Controller\ExampleController::class => 'doSomething',
            ]
        );
```

Next, I have created a file /theextension/Configuration/Typoscript/setup.typoscript that looks like this:

```
example_page = PAGE
example_page {
    typeNum = 776776

    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        additionalHeaders = Content-type:application/json
        xhtml_cleaning = 0
        debug = 0
        no_cache = 1
        admPanel = 0
    }
    10 < plugin.theextension_testing        
}
```

I am testing this by accessing the following URL in the browser and in Postman:

*/home?no_cache=1&pagetype=776776&tx_theextension_testing%5Baction%5D=doSomething&tx_theextension_testing%5Bcontroller%5D=Example&type=776776&cHash=f63ebddb3625ec605e51b6ba07cf0731*

The response is 200 OK and empty. The line "error_log" in my controller action is not called.
If I change the last line of my TypoScript to:

```
10 = TEXT
10.value = ExampleText
```

I do get "ExampleText" returned. So the TypoScript definition, typeNUM and resulting above URL are working, but I cannot get it to call the controller action. I have also tried:
10 < tt_content.list.20.theextension_testing
but the result was the same.

Can anybody help pointing me in the right direction?
I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the pluginName, extensionName and vendorName as well in your TypoScript code. It should look like this:

```
ajaxSearch_page = PAGE
ajaxSearch_page {
    typeNum = 776776
    10 = USER
    10.userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    10.extensionName= ExtensionName
    10.pluginName = PluginName
    10.vendorName = Vendor

   config {
      disableAllHeaderCode = 1
      additionalHeaders = Content-type:application/json
      xhtml_cleaning = 0
      debug = 0
      no_cache = 1
      admPanel = 0
   }
}
```

Maybe this answer will get you the wished results

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61637195/7162477

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! 
Small caveat: I could not manage to control the action of the controller via TypoScript. though, so for two different actions I created two different plugins and defined two separate typeNum page definitions.